# Как совместить работу aiogram и schedule на Тelegram bot

Tags: python, telegram, asyncio, aiogram, schedule

Хочу отправить каждый день в определенное время отправить сообщение подписчикам.
Использую библиотеку schedule и aiogram

```
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher
from aiogram.types import *
from aiogram.utils import executor
import schedule






bot = Bot()
dp = Dispatcher(bot)


async def send_message():
   await bot.send_messa@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])



async def start(message : Message):
    await bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, open('static/img/qq.jpg', 'rb'))


await schedule.every().day.at("10:30").do(send_message)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```

Comment: это так не работает )

Answer (score 14):

Вместо `schedule` можно использовать её асинхронную версию - [aioschedule](https://pypi.org/project/aioschedule/).

Вот пример кода:

```
import asyncio
import aioschedule

async def noon_print():
    print("It's noon!")

async def scheduler():
    aioschedule.every().day.at("12:00").do(noon_print)
    while True:
        await aioschedule.run_pending()
        await asyncio.sleep(1)

async def on_startup(_):
    asyncio.create_task(scheduler())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=False, on_startup=on_startup)
```

`executor.start_polling` запускает функцию, указанную аргументом `on_startup` на старте. В этот момент у нас уже существует `event_loop`, что позволяет нам запустить планировщик "параллельной" (насколько асинхронный код может быть параллельным) задачей при помощи `asyncio.create_task(scheduler())`.

Comment: Большое спасибо за подсказку с callback'ом `on_startup`!

Answer (score 0):

```py
async def send_message():
   await bot.send_messa@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
```

Что за конструкция такая "bot.send_messa@dp.message"?

```py
await schedule.every().day.at("10:30").do(send_message)
```

schedule.every() не является асинхронной функцией, которую нужно ожидать, хотя мы впринципе ничего не можем ожидать вне асинхронных функций.

```py
while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```

И тут находится венец всех ошибок, в вашем решении. В конце программы вы запускаете асинхронный event loop, который отслеживает события, но при этом чуть выше вы помещаете своего "бота" в синхронный бесконечный цикл, при этом еще и используя time.sleep().
schedule не может запустить выполнение вашей корутины. Вместо этого лучше использовать datetime как предложено здесь: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51292027/how-to-schedule-a-task-in-asyncio-so-it-runs-at-a-certain-date
А так же изучить как все это работает:
https://geekbrains.ru/posts/python_threading_part1
https://proglib.io/p/python-asyncio/

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать datetime

```
import datetime
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, types, executor
import logging
from config import TOKEN

print(datetime.datetime.today())
print(datetime.datetime.now())

d1 = datetime.datetime.today()
print(d1)

d1 = d1+datetime.timedelta(days=1)
if d1.strftime("%M%S") == "0300":
    print('lol')

print(d1.strftime("%M%S"))

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
bot = Bot(TOKEN)
dp = Dispatcher(bot)


@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def bot_not_know(message: types.Message):
    await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Start!")
    while True:
        if d1.strftime("%M%S") == "1300":  # в 13 минут 00 секунд будет сказано LOL
            await message.answer('LOL')


@dp.message_handler()
async def bot_not_know(message: types.Message):
    await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Чел ты чё несёшь!?")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```