# Как совместить работу aiohttp с aioschedule и aiogram

Tags: python, aiogram, asyncio, aiohttp

Пишу телеграм бота на `aiogram`, одна из его функций - показывать баланс моих аккаунтов с [market.csgo.com](https://market.csgo.com/). Функция работает в асинхронном режиме, отправляются запросы к API и выводится информация через `await bot.send_message`. Сейчас запуск функции реализован через кнопку клавиатуры. Код:

```
...

async def get_balance(session, profiles_dict, message):
    async with session.get(f'https://market.csgo.com/api/v2/get-money?key={profiles_dict[1][1]}') as resp:
        html_1 = await resp.json()

        each_wallet = int(html_1['money'])

        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, f'{profiles_dict[1][0]}: {each_wallet} ₽')


@dp.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
async def main(message):
    profiles = users()

    async with aiohttp.ClientSession(trust_env=True) as session:
        tasks = []

        if message.text == 'Balance ':
            await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Information request. Wait..')

            for i in profiles.items():
                task = asyncio.ensure_future(get_balance(session, i, message, stats))
                tasks.append(task)
            await asyncio.gather(*tasks)

        if message.text == 'Check Ban':
            ...

        if message.text == 'List Accounts':
            ...


if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=False)
```

Но как сделать так, что  бы функция вызывалась, допустим каждый час? Я знаю что существует асинхронная версия планировщика `aioschedule` и видел [этот пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1144849/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%83-aiogram-%D0%B8-schedule-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%A2elegram-bot). Но там запускают функцию без аргументов, у меня же их целых 3. Я пытался сделать так:

```
async def scheduler(session, profiles_dict, message):
    aioschedule.every().day.at("12:00").do(get_balance(session, profiles_dict, message))
    while True:
        await aioschedule.run_pending()
        await asyncio.sleep(1)


async def on_startup(session, profiles_dict, message):
    asyncio.create_task(scheduler(session, profiles_dict, message))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=False, on_startup=on_startup(session, profiles_dict, message))
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но очевидно, что это так не работает. От сюда и вопрос: **Как запустить функцию, которая выполняет асинхронные запросы `aiohttp` через планировщик `aioschedule` и результат отправить сообщением в телеграм `aiogram`?**

Comment: https://schedule.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples.html#pass-arguments-to-a-job

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение:

```
import aiogram
import asyncio
import aiohttp
import aioschedule

...

async def get_balance(session, profiles_dict):
    async with session.get(f'https://market.csgo.com/api/v2/get-money?key={profiles_dict[1][1]}') as resp:
        html = await resp.json()

        each_wallet = int(html['money'])

        await bot.send_message(MY_TELEGRAM_ID,
            f' <a href="{profiles_dict[1][0]}">{profiles_dict[0]}</a> : <i>{each_wallet}</i>',
            disable_web_page_preview=True, parse_mode=types.ParseMode.HTML)

...

@dp.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
async def main(message):
    profiles = users()

    async with aiohttp.ClientSession(trust_env=True) as session:
        tasks = []

        if message.text == 'Balance ':
            await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Information request. Wait..')

            for i in profiles.items():
                task = asyncio.ensure_future(get_balance(session, i))
                tasks.append(task)
            await asyncio.gather(*tasks)

        if message.text == 'On Sale ':
            ...

        if message.text == 'Timeout Items ⌛':
            ...


# Client session get_balance function
async def session_get_balance():
    profiles = users()

    async with aiohttp.ClientSession(trust_env=True) as session:
        tasks = []

        for i in profiles.items():
            task = asyncio.ensure_future(get_balance(session, i))
            tasks.append(task)
        await asyncio.gather(*tasks)


# Schedule functions by time
async def scheduler():
    aioschedule.every().hour.do(session_get_balance)
    while True:
        await aioschedule.run_pending()
        await asyncio.sleep(1)


# Function at start
async def on_startup(_):
    asyncio.create_task(scheduler())


# Launch telegram bot
if __name__ == "__main__":
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True, on_startup=on_startup)
```

Так как это мой персональный бот, вместо `message.from_user.id` я написал свой telegram id `MY_TELEGRAM_ID`. Все работает отлично.

```
await bot.send_message(MY_TELEGRAM_ID,
            f' <a href="{profiles_dict[1][0]}">{profiles_dict[0]}</a> : <i>{each_wallet}</i>',
            disable_web_page_preview=True, parse_mode=types.ParseMode.HTML)
```