# aioschedule и aiogram. Отложенный запуск функции

Tags: python, aiogram, aioschedule

Пишу бота на aiogram. У меня есть АСИНХРОННАЯ функция start_send_messages и мне нужно, чтобы бот вызывал эту функцию каждое утро. [Этот топик не помог](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1442052/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d1%83-aiohttp-%d1%81-aioschedule-%d0%b8-aiogram).
Файл с функционалом бота:

```
async def scheduler():
    aioschedule.every().day.at("8:00").do(start_send_messages)

    while True:
        await aioschedule.run_pending()
        await asyncio.sleep(1)


async def start_task():
    asyncio.create_task(scheduler())
```

Файл с запуском бота и вызовом функции scheduler, которая должна вызывать функцию start_send_messages:

```
from aiogram import Dispatcher
.......
from bot.utils.user.other import start_task

async def __on_start_up(dp: Dispatcher) -> None:
    start_task()
    register_all_filters(dp)
    register_all_handlers(dp)


def start_bot():
    bot = Bot(token=TgKeys.TOKEN, parse_mode="HTML")
    dp = Dispatcher(bot, storage=MemoryStorage())
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True, on_startup=__on_start_up)
```

При запуске этого кода бот работает исправно, но вызова функции не происходит. Вот варнинги:

```
  start_task()
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
```

Answer (score 0):

Лол. Честно, перед тем как задать вопрос много информации перерыл, но как-то пропустил решение.

```
aioschedule.every().day.at("23:23").do(start_send_messages)

    while True:
        await aioschedule.run_pending()
        await asyncio.sleep(1)


async def start_task():
    asyncio.create_task(scheduler())


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.create_task(start_task())
```